# display 2 table in index.php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I wan to display 2 table in index.php. Display the same data from 1 database. But it not appearing. See image below

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm0vE.png)

and here is my code (index.php)

```css
<?php

 include("dbcon.php");  
 
 $link=$cn;
    $i=0;
 $result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `node` ORDER BY `tarikh` DESC LIMIT 1");
 
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sensor Data1</title>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">  
   </head>
<body>
   <Center><h1>Sensor Readings</h1>
   <h1>Node 1</h2>


   <table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;No&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Waktu / Tarikh&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Temperature &nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Humidity &nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Length(CM)&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Node&nbsp;</td> 
  </tr>

  
      <?php 
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%d </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
             ++$i, $row["tarikh"], $row["temperature"], $row["humidity"], $row["height"], $row["node"]);
       }  
    
      ?>

   </table></center>
   
    <center><table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;No&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Waktu / Tarikh&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Temperature &nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Humidity &nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Length(CM)&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Node&nbsp;</td> 
  </tr>
  
  <?php 
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%d </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
             ++$i, $row["tarikh"], $row["temperature1"], $row["humidity1"], $row["height"], $row["node"]);
       }  
    
      ?></center>
</body>
</html>
```

can correct my code to make it appears?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason your second table didn't print was that the $result got moved to the end in the first while loop.

If I'm right the quick and easy solution would be to rerun the sql query right before the second loop as follows.

```css
<?php

 include("dbcon.php");  
 
 $link=$cn;
    $i=0;
 $result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `node` ORDER BY `tarikh` DESC LIMIT 1");
 
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sensor Data1</title>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">  
   </head>
<body>
   <Center><h1>Sensor Readings</h1>
   <h1>Node 1</h2>


   <table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;No&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Waktu / Tarikh&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Temperature &nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Humidity &nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Length(CM)&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Node&nbsp;</td> 
  </tr>

  
      <?php 
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%d </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
             ++$i, $row["tarikh"], $row["temperature"], $row["humidity"], $row["height"], $row["node"]);
       }  
    
      ?>

   </table></center>
   
    <center><table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;No&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Waktu / Tarikh&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Temperature &nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Humidity &nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Length(CM)&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;Node&nbsp;</td> 
  </tr>
  
  <?php 


       $result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `node` ORDER BY `tarikh` DESC LIMIT 1");
 
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%d </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
             ++$i, $row["tarikh"], $row["temperature1"], $row["humidity1"], $row["height"], $row["node"]);
       }  
    
      ?></center>
</body>
</html>
```

though I have never done used this(I just found it with a quick search for resetting a $result). you might be able to use mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); that would be faster I think as it would not need to re-fetch the data.